# Output something right before \end{environment}, regardless of commands output inside that environment

Tags: macros, environments

In the following example, the sentence `{\bfseries Please move me to the very end of the mainentry environment?}` is placed at the very bottom of the definition of the `mainentry` environment.

Nevertheless, it the sentence is not placed at the very end of the issuing of that environment. As you can see, the sub-commands (e.g. `subentry1`) issued within that environment are output after the sentence.

I would like to have the sentence placed at the very end of the issuing of that environment. That is: output the sentence right before the `\end{mainentry}` so to speak.

## MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\IfEmptyTF\tl_if_blank:nTF
\cs_set_eq:NN\Trim\tl_trim_spaces:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newenvironment {mainentry} {\mainentryA}{}
\def\mainentryA#1#2{%
%
   \def\subentryone##1{%
##1
  }%
%
  \IfEmptyTF{#2}{%
#1
  }{
#1 #2
  }
%
{\bfseries Please move me to the very end of the mainentry environment?}
%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mainentry}{main1}{main2} \subentryone{subentry1} \subentryone{subentry2} \end{mainentry} \endgraf
\begin{mainentry}{main1}{} \subentryone{subentry1} \end{mainentry}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\newenvironment{<env>}{<begin>}{<end>}` performs `<end>` with a call to `\end{<env>}`, so place the text you want to appear around the end of `<env>` in that component of the definition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\IfEmptyTF\tl_if_blank:nTF
\cs_set_eq:NN\Trim\tl_trim_spaces:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newenvironment{mainentry}
  {\mainentryA}
  {{\bfseries Please move me to the very end of the mainentry environment?}}
\def\mainentryA#1#2{%
%
   \def\subentryone##1{%
##1
  }%
%
  \IfEmptyTF{#2}{%
#1
  }{
#1 #2
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mainentry}{main1}{main2}
  \subentryone{subentry1}
  \subentryone{subentry2}
\end{mainentry}

\begin{mainentry}{main1}{}
  \subentryone{subentry1}
\end{mainentry}

\end{document}
```